# How the third-party dependencies (Say axios, loadash, vuex, etc.) gets loaded for remote modules in case of Module Federation?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack-module-federation

I have a host app and in it, I am loading three remote applications leveraging Module Federation of Webpack. How do the third-party npm libraries for remotes get loaded when loading the remoteEntry.js? What is the flow here?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#low-level-concepts